# Compiling multiple XSD into single JAR using XMLBeans

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I have the following directory structure:

```
schema1
    schema1.xsd
    schema1.xsdconfig
schema2
    schema2.xsd
    schema2.xsdconfig
schema3
    schema3.xsd
    schema3.xsdconfig
```

I am trying to compile all of these into a single JAR file using XMLBeans, but cannot work out the scomp command line to compile all of this together.  I need a separate XSDConfig file for each XSD due to limitations in the incoming XML, and the requirement to force a different namespace onto each of these files.

How would I specify these files to be combined into a single JAR using `scomp`?

When I try to compile them I get the following message:

```
/Users/chris/development/iservice/sstp-gateway/schema/OrderTracking/request/orderTrackingReq.xsd:3:2: error: sch-props-correct.2: Duplicate global element: Session (Original global element found in file: response/orderTrackingResp.xsd)
Time to build schema type system: 0.603 seconds
BUILD FAILED
```

I don't know how to bind each individual xsdconfig to each xsd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [this](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/antXmlbean.html). You can compile multiple schema at once using the XMLBean ant task.

Comment: Put the .xsdconfig file in the same directory as the .xsd that you are compiling

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have problem with Session element, specified in response/orderTrackingResp.xsd. Consider rename it or add response/orderTrackingResp.xsdconfig where you can change namespace and other generated properties.